# Maximum Entropy Principle with inequality constraints

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, probability, information

It is well known that, maximizing the entropy of the joint distribution $P(x_1,...,x_n)$ of a random vector $(X_1,...,X_n)$ subject to equality constraints for the mean vector ($\mu$) and the variance covariance matrix ($\Sigma$) one obtains the multivariate normal $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$.

My question is about the case where one can impose only inequality constraint. In particular, I would be interested in relaxing the constraints on the off diagonal entries of the variance-covariance matrix (whereas I would be willing to mantain equality constraints on the vector of means and variances). Cases of interest, for my problem, would be:

1. Constraining a certain number of covariances to zero, while letting the others unconstrained. I.e. studying the problem under $\Sigma_{ij}=0$ for some $i\neq j$
2. Imposing, on top of the above constraint, also inequality constraints, specifying the sign of the entries, but not their value. I.e. allowing for inequality constraints of the form $\Sigma_{ij}\geq 0$ and  $\Sigma_{ij}\leq 0$ for some $i\neq j$ (I guess strict inequalities may cause problems with the existence of the solution).

Any help or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Would this be better suited for Math SE?

Comment: Related, math SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2029707/532409, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3131807/532409, wiki (section: distributions with measured constants, continuous case) deals with the inequality case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution

Comment: Thanks! @TobiasFünke you are right, I will post there.